Unable to erase brand new SSD with APFS
I've been unable to set up a new SSD for a friend. The plan is to use it for the internal drive on their Mac.
Using Disk Utility:
Erase -> Format:APFS Scheme:GUID Partition Map

Two drives have been tried, and the USB interface is brand new too.
The actual process I'm trying to follow is How to Clone Your Old Drive to New SSD in macOS for MacBook Pro, etc. However the Mac taking the new drive fails to do the AFPS too. Which is why I'm resorting to using my Mac and the USB interface.
This video shows the error: https://youtu.be/3puRNax9Cc8

13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports
Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)

I've seen is suggested that USB >2 might be the issue, but that doesn't explain why the SSD mounted internally is also having issues. Different formats work.
Any clues greatly appreciated.
Edit, additional info:
Managed to potentially make progress. I think I have the drive configured correctly using Recovery Mode. Something I had been using from the very beginning.
Erasure works and all the details look right.
However I get errors whichever way I try to restore. Photos of screen incoming - the external drive is not mounted in the photographs, but I did mount and retry with no difference.



You made the video private, so I can't watch it. Usually when this sort of thing happens, it's because the drive has the wrong kind of partition table. Instead of just erasing it, partition it as GUID in Disk Utility.

The video is unlisted now, apologies, and shows I am using Disk Utility with GUID Partition Map selected. I'll take a look and see if there are any other ways I might be doing this.

Have you explored what  69842 means? Quick web search suggests this may be a hardware issue, other says APFS!

Searched, but second brand new drive… must be something else the matter.

Is that a second brand new enclosure or a second SSD inside one enclosure?

Please start up in Recovery mode, launch Disk Utility, and try again. If it still fails, you're dealing with a hardware fault. Just make sure you don't erase the wrong drive.

Yeah been trying Recovery Mode. Must be faulty USB. Here is my plan, I have a long weekend away ahead, but I'll order 2x SATA enclosures compliant with USB 3. I'll use my Mac to do the cloning using Carbon Copy Cloner (seen that dotted around forums). I'll take any other recommendations, I've also seen on forums that the SATA cable in the old Mac may be damaged, worth buying one of those too?

I’m seeing things like the source not being valid… also now I have two enclosures, both plugged into my Mac and trying to use Disk Utility in Recovery Mode. If I try to recover from OLD to NEW the OLD volume is not in the list of options. The opposite is true if I select to recover from the NEW to OLD. So I suspect that the old drive (which itself is not original) has issues itself.

Are you booted the internet recovery? If so, which version of macOS is internet recovery using?

Mac OS Utilities 1.0 (33) I’m thinking the best course of action now is recover from Time Machine backup that he has. QQ: Should I install Mac OS before TM recovery, or does TM do that bit too?

Please see the answer to my other question here New SSD only bootable via USB, not SATA
Essentially, the SSD was not compatible with the Early 2011 MacBook Pro's SATA interface.
Buy from a retailer who associates the hardware directly with your device, such as Mr Memory: https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/ssd-upgrades/apple/macbook-pro/15-inch-early-2011-2.3ghz-core-i7

Very good details and super glad you have resolution on this. Let’s close this to the other question but keep them both up to allow anyone searching to find the main thread. Thanks for answering and doing the work to document what happened.
